# TFS rest API, bypass gated on create changeset

Tags: tfs, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a deprecated C# program that edits a file in TFS on premise source control.  I am in the process of porting this to the rest api.  With the C# API I used the CheckIn method of the Workspace which allows me to bypass the gated check-in.  I can't seem to find a responding rest API, but I can use the [create changeset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/changesets/create?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1) call.

The create changeset call works but it kicks of the gated check-in.  I have privileges to bypass this and I can bypass it with the C# dotNet API.

How do I bypass the gated check-in with the restAPI?

Answer (score 0):

Bypass gated check-in is not supported in Create Changeset REST API. I submitted a user voice that you can vote: [Create changeset Rest API bypass gated check in](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1017512/create-changeset-rest-api-bypass-gated-check-in.html)